# modeless dialog tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, non-modal

I'm using a class called customDialog, based on Based on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm
The standard code creates a class which subclasses `Toplevel`, and creates modal dialogs.
I'm trying to adapt the code so it can also create modeless dialogs. The standard code calls the `Toplevel` constructor, creates the dialog and then does  `self.wait_window(self)` at the end, which waits until the dialog window is dismissed.
But I'm not succeeding.

My naive attempt was to simply skip the `wait_window()` (that's the attempt in my code snipped below). I've tried a few other things, but the dialog remains modal, that is, I can't interact with the application's main window. What is forcing it to be modal? The dialogs contain widgets and a few buttons, typically.

```
class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title = None,modal=True):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.transient(parent)
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.parent = parent
        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        #register validators
        self.validatePosInt = (body.register(self.OnValidatePosInt),
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)   #this calls the body function which is overridden, and which draws the dialog
        body.grid()
        self.buttonbox()
        self.grab_set()
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+50,
                                  parent.winfo_rooty()+50))
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()

        if modal:
            self.wait_window(self)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the line that says `self.grab_set()`. A "grab" means to grab all events and direct them toward this window, which you don't want.

If you read a bit deeper into the web page where you got the code you'll see that it mentions this exact line and why it is there:

> ... Next, the constructor creates the dialog body, and then calls
>   grab_set to make the dialog modal

Comment: thanks greatly for the answer. Re the comment you referred to, I must have read over it a few times and didn't understand its significance.